# DataTable in partial view

Tags: datatables, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have datatable in _layout that works fine all other tables except this particular one I have in a partial view perhaps because of the way the data is loaded.

_layout.cshtml

```
    $('.dataTableList').DataTable({ responsive: true, "autoWidth": false });
```

Detail.cshtml

```
    <div class="inventory" data-url=@Url.Action("Inventory")>...</div>
```

Load div table:

```
    $('.inventory').each(function (index, item) {
        var url = $(item).data("url");
        if (url && url.length > 0) {
            $(item).load(url); 
        }
    });
```

Controller-Action

```
    public ActionResult Inventory()
    {              
        return PartialView("Inventory", inventoryService.Get());
    }
```

Partial Inventory view

```
    <table class="table table-striped dataTableList">
        <thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead> <tbody>...</tbody></table>
```

How do I get datatable initialization from _layout to work on this table? I see that if i initialize datatable only in partial view and not in layout, it works fine. But then I would have to initialize it on all my other partial views individually. There has to be a better way. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: You might get more help if you add tags for the framework you're using as well.

Answer (score 0):

after loading your partial view html, try to call something like `$('#partialViewDataTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();`